# Showing picture taken from camera: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-camera

I am trying to show the picture taken by the camera and sometimes it works but it usually gives me the error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:727)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:703)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:741)
     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:847)
     at com.dima.polimi.rentall.NewProduct.onActivityResult(NewProduct.java:207)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5773)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3710)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3757)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:170)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried the solutions from multiple questions but i never make it to work

This is my code:

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
```

dispatchTakePictureIntent

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.i("", "IOException");
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  // prefix
            ".jpg",         // suffix
            storageDir      // directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            Bitmap mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use an [image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), that can intelligently downsample the image to fit the `ImageView`, and therefore take up less memory. It will also do that work on a background thread, rather than doing that work on the main application thread, as you are doing here (freezing your UI while that is happening).

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tried, using: Picasso.with(this).load(mCurrentPhotoPath).into(mImageView); but it doesn't load it

Comment: `mCurrentPhotoPath` is neither a valid filesystem path nor a valid `Uri`. Hold onto `image`, and try using that `File` object.

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile();`. You should not create that file your self. Leave it to the camera app. You should only provide the name/uri. Better remove it.

Comment: Further you should resize the image while you construct a bitmap out of it. Code to do that has been posted a hundred times here. Google for justDecodeBounds.

Comment: I have tried with image and storageDir and still not showing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it to work, the solution is using bitmap like this:

```
 Bitmap b = BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(image.getAbsolutePath(), 540, 360);
```

BitmapUtility:

```
public class BitmapUtility {

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
private static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
} }
```